# Using Graphics to Draw a BufferedImage with AlphaBlending Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, alphablending

I do a lot of game programming in my free time, and am currently working on a game engine library.  Previous to this point I have made customized per game engines built straight into the application, however, to challenge my logical skills even further, I decided I wanted to make an engine that I could literally use with any game that I write, kind of like a plugin.

Before this point, I have been pulling textures in using a BufferedImage using getRBG to pull the pixel[] out and by hand writing over the background int[] with the texture int[] array in the (X,Y) position that the Renderable resided.  Then when everything was written to the master int[] I would make a new BufferedImage and use setRGB using the master int[] and use a BufferStrategy and it's Graphic to drawImage of the BufferedImage.  I liked this method because I felt like i had complete control over the way things were rendered, but I don't think it was very efficient.

Here is a look at the way I used to write to the master int[]

```
public void draw(Render render, int x, int y, float alphaMul){
    for(int i=0; i<render.Width; i++){
        int xPix = i + x;
        if(Width - 1<xPix || xPix<0)continue;
        for(int j=0; j<render.Height; j++){
            int yPix = j + y;
            if(Height - 1<yPix || yPix<0)continue;

            int srcARGB = render.Pixels[i + j * render.Width];
            int dstARGB = Pixels[xPix + yPix * Width];

            int srcAlpha = (int)((0xFF & (srcARGB >> 24))*alphaMul);
            int srcRed = 0xFF & (srcARGB >> 16);
            int srcGreen = 0xFF & (srcARGB >> 8);
            int srcBlue = 0xFF & (srcARGB);

            int dstAlpha = 0xFF & (dstARGB >> 24);
            int dstRed = 0xFF & (dstARGB >> 16);
            int dstGreen = 0xFF & (dstARGB >> 8);
            int dstBlue = 0xFF & (dstARGB);

            float srcAlphaF = srcAlpha/255.0f;
            float dstAlphaF = dstAlpha/255.0f;


            int outAlpha = (int)((srcAlphaF + (dstAlphaF)*(1 - (srcAlphaF)))*255);

            int outRed = (int)(srcRed*srcAlphaF) + (int)(dstRed * (1 - srcAlphaF));
            int outGreen = (int)(srcGreen*srcAlphaF) + (int)(dstGreen * (1 - srcAlphaF));
            int outBlue = (int)(srcBlue*srcAlphaF) + (int)(dstBlue * (1 - srcAlphaF));

            int outARGB = (outAlpha<<24)|(outRed << 16) | (outGreen << 8) | (outBlue);

            Pixels[xPix + yPix * Width] = outARGB;
        }
    }
}
```

I have recently found out it may be multitudes faster, where using drawImage I can loop through all of the Renderables and draw them as BufferedImages using their respective (X,Y) positions.  But, I do not know how to work alphaBlending with that. So my questions are, how would I go about getting the results that I want?, and Would it be resource and time beneficial over my previous method?

Thanks
-Craig

Comment: Have you looked at AlphaComposite?

Comment: A little, to be honest I'm not that familiar with it.  Nor do I know how to implement it with my current setup.  Can it be used with Graphics or does it require Graphics2D?

Comment: You'll need `Graphics2D`, which `BufferedImage` returns to you, see [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: This very well may sound dumb or be worded incorrectly, but I don't think I can use Graphics2D with BufferStrategy can i?

Comment: Yes, `BufferStrategy#getDrawGraphics` should return an instance of `Graphics2D`, but you'll need to cast it.  If not, render it all to a `BufferedImage` first

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help.  If you would like to add that as an answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: Just curious though.  Do you think that using this route would be more efficient than the one that I was previously using?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, getRGB is very slow, you're working with a abstract layer over a implementation of directx/OpenGL so you might as well take advantage of it. Bliting images will also be faster then using the graphics primitive methods in most case.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: [Compositing Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) from the Java2D tutorial. (Yes, sorry, I know I'm late to the party)

Comment: I have been looking into that and correct me if I'm wrong, but that only allows me to specify a certain alpha value for a whole image that is being drawn to the screen.  And will not work for images that have different alpha values throughout it